# Exception in Chill-kryo

Tags: scala, serialization, kryo

I am trying to run the sample code for Chill-Scala from this  [link](https://github.com/xitrum-framework/chill-scala)

I have two dummy case classes

one is User

```
@SerialVersionUID(1)
case class User(name :String, age : Int) extends Serializable
```

and the other is Student

```
@SerialVersionUID(2)
case class Student(sub : String , id : Int , user : User) extends Serializable
```

here is my code for serialization  that i have modified  from this github example [twitter/chill repo](https://github.com/xitrum-framework/chill-scala)

```
object SeriDeseri {
  private val kryo = {
    val a = KryoSerializer.registerAll
    val k = new Kryo
    a(k)
    k
  }

  def toBytes(student : Student): Array[Byte] = {
    println("********** serializing")
    val b = new ByteArrayOutputStream
    val o = new Output(b)
    kryo.writeObject(o, student)
    o.close()
    b.toByteArray
  }

  def fromBytes[Student](bytes: Array[Byte])(implicit m: Manifest[Student]): Option[Student] = {
    println("********** Deserializing")
    val i = new Input(bytes)
    try {
      val t = kryo.readObject(i, m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Student]])
      Option(t)
    } catch {
      case NonFatal(e) => None
    } finally {
      i.close()
    }
  }
}
```

here is the code for my Main class

```
val user = new User( "Ahsen", 14)
val stu = new Student("oop", 12, user)

  val serial : Array[Byte] = SeriDeseri.toBytes(stu)
  val deserial :Option[Student] = SeriDeseri.fromBytes(serial)
  val obj  = deserial match{
    case Some(objec) => println(objec)
    case None => println("----------- Nothing was deserialized")
  }
```

Now the problem is when i run this code it gives me `java.lang.InstantiationError: scala.runtime.Nothing$` exception

here are complete stack traces

> [info] Running kryotest.Main
>
> ********** serializing
>
> ********** Deserializing 
>   [error] (run-main-0) java.lang.InstantiationError: scala.runtime.Nothing$
>   java.lang.InstantiationError: scala.runtime.Nothing$  at
>   scala.runtime.Nothing$ConstructorAccess.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo$DefaultInstantiatorStrategy$1.newInstance(Kryo.java:1193)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1061)   at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.create(FieldSerializer.java:547)
>     at
>   com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:523)
>     at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:657)     at
>   com.test.hcast_serializer.SeriDeseri$.fromBytes(SeriDeseri.scala:32)
>     at kryotest.Main$.delayedEndpoint$kryotest$Main$1(Main.scala:31)    at
>   kryotest.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:9)    at
>   scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)    at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:383)   at
>   scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
>     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)   at
>   kryotest.Main$.main(Main.scala:9)     at kryotest.Main.main(Main.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [trace] Stack
>   trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1  at
>   scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27) [trace] Stack trace
>   suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output. [error]
>   (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1 [error] Total time: 4 s, completed
>   Aug 31, 2015 3:15:54 PM

Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

Edit: when i replaced  the following line from `fromBytes` method

`val t = kryo.readObject(i, m.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[Student]])`

with

```
val t = kryo.readClassAndObject(i).asInstanceOf[Student]
```

i dont excatly know what happened after the modification but it did not give me the exception but the method returned `None` instead of the object

output after the modification

```
********** serializing
********** Deserializing
----------- Nothing was deserialized
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first line of the example in the git repository for your example  say Chill now supports Scala 2.11. Please use it instead.

There is an easy way of serializing scala objects using [chill from twitter](https://github.com/twitter/chill/tree/60bc5a8e36b2d5adf7261dcc0599486f07bb4900)

here is what they said:

> Chill-bijection
>
> Bijections and Injections are useful when considering serialization.
>   If you have an Injection from T to Array[Byte] you have a
>   serialization. Additionally, if you have a Bijection between A and B,
>   and a serialization for B, then you have a serialization for A. See
>   BijectionEnrichedKryo for easy interop between bijection and chill.
>   KryoInjection: easy serialization to byte Arrays
>
> KryoInjection is an injection from Any to Array[Byte]. To serialize
>   using it:
>
> import com.twitter.chill.KryoInjection
>
> val bytes:  Array[Byte]    = KryoInjection(someItem) val tryDecode:
>   scala.util.Try[Any] = KryoInjection.invert(bytes)
>
> KryoInjection can be composed with Bijections and Injections from
>   com.twitter.bijection.

So I rewrite your main class:

```
object Main extends App {

  val user = new User( "Ahsen", 14)
  val stu = new Student("oop", 12, user)



  val bytes:  Array[Byte]    = KryoInjection(stu)

  println("Serialized byte array:" + bytes)

  val tryDecode: scala.util.Try[Any] = KryoInjection.invert(bytes)

  println(tryDecode)

}
```

and for your build.sbt use this:

```
"com.twitter" % "chill-bijection_2.11" % "0.7.0"
```

And finally I get this result:

```
[info] Running chill.Main 
Serialized byte array:[B@17e5b410
Success(Student(oop,12,User(Ahsen,14)))
```

Comment: one more thing i want to ask , Does the serializer need to be an object ? Are the toBytes and fromBytes methods static? or we can use them in simple classes?

Comment: The KryoInjection is a scala object, and in this case you use the methods invert and apply, and this is the way that Twitter suggested on github, take a look at the class implementation https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/60bc5a8e36b2d5adf7261dcc0599486f07bb4900/chill-bijection/src/main/scala/com/twitter/chill/KryoInjection.scala